# How to patch classes in multi-module setup - Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

Here is an example directory structure, created for patching classes in `java.base`, `java.logging`:

```
src
  +- java.base
     + module-info.java
     +- java
        +- lang
            +- Object.java

  +- java.logging
     + module-info.java
     +- java
        +- util
            +- logging
                +- FileHandler.java
```

Assume that both `Object.java` and `FileHandler.java` are modified. For example when compiling FileHandler.java it should only use the locally modified Object.java for the compilation.

Currently I created module descriptors in both 'java.base', and 'java.logging' directories (with empty bodies) though I'm not sure if this is the right way to proceed.

**java.base/module-info.java**

```
module java.base {
}
```

**java.logging/module-info.java**

```
module java.logging {
}
```

If I do:

```
javac --patch-module java.base=src/java.logging -module-source-path src
-d build
```

- Will it use the modified `Object.java` for patching the classes in
  `java.logging` module directory?
- It also seems to me that declaring module descriptors like this overrides the whole module and not just the classes, so how can I preserve the classes in the original module?

It would be great if I could patch several classes which belongs to different modules at once.

Comment: Once you the empty module-info.java files then I would expect this should work: `javac --module-source-path=src --patch-module java.base=src/java.base --patch-module java.logging=src/java.logging -d build $(find src -name "*.java")`

Comment: Ty. Can this be used when there are non-module classes in the src tree? For example I get `error: not in a module on the module source path` if I tried something like: `javac --module-source-path=src/modules src/NonModuleClass.java`